# what to be used for constant interaction(for every 3 mins) with server and showing alert to user in android

Tags: android, service, intentservice

In my application i want to check any new orders are there for every 5 minutes.if any new order came,i want to show alert box in any activity of my app and if the app is in back ground(not visible) i want to show notification

Comment: what should i use service or intent service, and in that what should i use to load data from web.

Comment: How often are you expecting orders to come?  If it isn't very often, you might want to take a look at Firebase Cloud Messaging, and arrange for the server to inform the app when an order arrives - it will use less battery

Comment: for every 5 minutes i want to check the new order, and do not want to use Firebase cloud messaging.

Answer (score 0):

A service class with scheduler with fixed rate of time is better to do and for contacting with main ui use result receiver.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Service, Thread for it, or you can make it in the Activity (not good).
In the Service/Thread/Activity use a CountDownTimer or sleep() with an infinity while loop. So:

```
boolean b= true;
    CountDownTimer cd = new CountDownTimer(3*60*1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //Nothing comes here
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Here comes the server request
        }
    };
    while(b){
        cd.start();
    }
```

or so:

```
 boolean b= true;
    while(b){
        //Here comes the request
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3*60*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thease methods are going to work, but thease are going to use a lot of energy, so be carefull with them.

Comment: without consuming lot of energy, and i want to start downloading the content as soon as service starts and want to show alert box in the currently opened screen of my app, if the app is in background i want to show notification, so please understand clearly.